# Browser opening, but failing to load localhost page--Selenium, MVC, C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, localhost

I am starting to write tests for a project that is in its 8th agile sprint.  I was brought on the team about one week ago.

Yesterday my Selenium tests were passing against the git master branch. I was accessing the http localhost address, opening it, running a test, and then closing the browser all from the Selenium code.

My team changed the access (somehow, don't quite understand) and the http localhost address changed.  This was yesterday evening.  Pulled the new code this morning from git.

I found the new address, and replaced it in my localhost constant.  Ran the tests. Now the tests open the browser, no localhost info is entered into the url, test times out, test fails. All I changed was the localhost address.

When I just run start from the Visual Studio ribbon start button, the web app will open two windows in the browser (Firefox default).  The team lead says that both windows are needed right now.

I am fairly new to Selenium (1 month and learning) and very new to .NET/Visual Studio/C# (day 4).

Researched the issue, only thing I have found that might make sense is creating an ASP.NET HTTP Module-- And I have read up on it, but don't know if it is THE solution.

If anybody has any other ideas, please let me know. 
thx
a

EDIT : CODE

```
 string URL = "http://localhost:54879/"; //unable to connect   
    ....
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
```

Comment: you will be able to solve this problem **MUCH** faster if you consult an architect who knows the regression system you're using.. We know nothing about the internal workings of your framework / systems.

Comment: You "changed the localhost address". Well where? Is this in some configuration value somewhere? Have you changed some IIS setting? Perhaps the physical IIS bindings? This doesn't sound a Selenium problem, more of a local environment issue.

Comment: 1-Okay, will not edit the comments, because I feel they highlight that I am very new at this, coming on an existing project of which I know very little about.

Comment: 2-I know nothing about the internal workings of the framework.  Our architect has inherited this project and is the third architect working on it, I have asked him for help too.  The various solutions he has suggested deal with adding project dependencies, changing the order of operations, etc.  Which did not change anything.

Comment: I changed the localhost address in my Selenium code to point to the new localhost address I was given.  This again, did nothing. Opened up console in firebug, and noticed that it was running on a different port that either of the addresses/ports I was given.  Again changed the localhost address to reflect the new port.  Now I am getting an 404 error, which means I am connecting, but the information is not there.

Comment: Lastly, I have not changed any IIS settings or bindings.  I agree that it may not be a Selenium problem, but it is surfacing when I use Selenium, so that is where I have to start tracking it from.

Comment: What is the version of Selenium and Firefox on your machine and environment?

Comment: So what's the difference in the URL Selenium is going to and the URL of the application? When you load up the application *manually*, what port does it sit at?

Comment: Selenium Version 2.39.0.0
Firefox Version 26.0

Comment: Edited the original question to show my code.  When I open the project manually it opens at: http://localhost:54879/ and connects, etc.  When I run my code, it will not connect.

Comment: @Abarendt How is IIS set up? Show us a screenshot of the bindings set up in IIS. You shouldn't need to start the app with *or* without debugging to get it do something. That's the whole point of IIS!

Comment: @Arran, Thank you so much for this information.  However, after I got the page object design pattern set up and running for the Selenium tests, I was moved to another project.  I do not have access to this project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Had our local Microsoft guru look at what was happening.  Tests run/console connects if I run after selecting start without debugging.  I am v. new to Visual Studio, so I guess it was set up wrong in my tray and this makes it run properly.

Comment: I do not feel that I can select my own answer as the correct answer even though it works.  If Arran is correct, my solution does not solve the deeper problems with the project, only covers them with a band-aid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that there was i needed to first run the programme without debuggen ( Debug > Start without Debugging).